# How to get only the tweets containing an image from people I follow?

Tags: image, twitter

Is it possible to only get the tweets containing an image from the people that I follow?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Was too quick to ask this.

Found one solution here.

http://sociable.co/social-media/search-twitter-like-a-pro-how-to-find-the-latest-images-photos-being-tweeted/